# Prevent JWT cookie to be used from another machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt

How can I secure a JWT access token by tying it to one machine?

I can take token value and cookie identity from a browser which is signed in to my site and has a valid token, to another browser and access authorized actions?

Answer (score 0):

You can always copy cookies from a browser where a user has logged in, and plug them into another browser on another machine and be authenticated that way.

If you want to prevent this, you could add a claim to the token that identifies the browser and/or the client, which will need to be verifyable on the server.

You could for example add the user agent and public IP address of the client, and verify this information from the token with each request on the server.

However, the user agent is fakeable and their public IP address might change.

Comment: CodeCaster, thanks for answer can you help me with link or reference include an example how can I add claim for token that identifies the browser.